# How to check ISNULL in Where clause for query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like:

```
    SELECT
        PLIR.ListItemID AS [value],
        Item.ActiveFlag,
        Item.ListItemCode
    FROM ListItem AS [Item] INNER JOIN ListItemRelationship AS [PLIR] ON Item.ListItemID = PLIR.ListItemID
    WHERE Item.ListCode = @ListCode
        AND Item.ListItemLongValue LIKE ISNULL('%'+@mask+'%', NULL)
        AND Item.ListItemID IN (SELECT ITEMS FROM dbo.Split(@id, '|'))
```

In the last line, my `@id` parameter can be null. How can I check the NULL for the `@id` parameter?

Comment: `ISNULL('%'+@mask+'%', NULL)` makes absolutely no sense, what is it trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IS NULL` with `OR`:

```
WHERE Item.ListCode = @ListCode
AND Item.ListItemLongValue LIKE ISNULL('%'+@mask+'%', NULL)
AND (
  @id IS NULL
  OR Item.ListItemID IN (SELECT ITEMS FROM dbo.Split(@id, '|'))
)
```